# How to show that a point is a constant distance from another point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a question stating

> $AB$ and $AC$ are two smooth fixed rails making angles $25^{\circ}$ and $65^{\circ}$ with the downward vertical, one on either side of it. A uniform rod $XY$ has rings at $X$ and $Y$, which can move along $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Show that, in any position of the rod, the centre of mass is at a constant distance from $A$.

Firstly, as the rod is uniform the centre of mass is at the midpoint of the rod. I have denoted the midpoint of $XY$ as $M$, the lengths $AX$ as $x$, $AY$ as $y$, $AM$ as $z$, and $XY$ as $2a$, and the angle $MAY$ as $\theta$. Here is a diagram I have drawn of the situation:
[image]

I think that I will need to find a relationship between $z$, $x$, and $y$ to show that $z$ is constant.

The first realtionship I found using pythagoras' theorem is $4a^2=x^2+y^2$, which may come in handy but i am not sure how. I also know that, using the cosine rule:
$$a^2 = z^2 + y^2 - 2zy\cos{\theta} \quad and \quad a^2 = z^2 + x^2 - 2zx\cos{(90-\theta)} $$
From this I get:
$$z^2 + y^2 - 2zy\cos{\theta} = z^2 + x^2 - 2zx\cos{(90-\theta)} $$
Which can be simplified to:
$$ y^2 - 2zy\cos{\theta} =  x^2 - 2zx\sin{\theta}  $$
It is at this point that I am not sure what to do. I have tried rearranging to get z on it's own, and to see if it cancels to a constant, and I arrived at $z = \frac{x^2 -y^2}{2x\sin{\theta} - 2zy\cos{\theta}} $, but this does not seem to have helped.

Comment: $\triangle XAY$ is always right angled. And we know that the distance of mid of hypotenuse to the $90^o$ vertex is one half the hypotenuse so done.

Comment: @ homing3951 Thank you. I didn't know that, makes it much simpler. Would you be able to direct me to a proof of that?

Comment: Just draw a circle with center $M$ and diameter $XY$, then using the fact that angle in a semicircle is $90^0$ one notes that $A$ will be on the circumference thus $MA$ will be radius which was half of $XY$

Answer (score 0):

I would ignore the angle. You have already found $x^2+y^2=4a^2$. I suggest you use a coordinate system, with $AB$ as first axis and $AC$ as second. So you get $X=(x,0), Y=(0,y)$ and from these you can derive $M=(X+Y)/2=(x/2,y/2)$. In this case, what's the distance between $A$ and $M$? Pythagoras again tells you it is $\sqrt{\left(\frac x2\right)^2+\left(\frac y2\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}4}=\lvert a\rvert$.